# Visual Studio 2013: breakpoint that combines Hit Count and Condition

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2013 Community/Professional, you can set breakpoint to `Hit Count` or `Condition`. Is possible to set breakpoint to have both ?

Comment: what is your exact visual studio version?

Comment: 2013, I will edit my question.

Comment: Which edition? Is it the express edition? Or standard, pro ornultimate?

Comment: Community/Professional

Comment: So what is the exact problem? Just set a breakpoint, set a condition and a hit count and youre all set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set both HitCount and Condition, at least I can to it in mi Visual Studio 2012 instance with no problem.

I see now that this is not available with the Express versions of Visual studio though

Comment: So you just add both hit count and condition, and they will not exclude each other ?

Comment: Hit count is only incremented when condition is true.